# css Not applying in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

[image]

```html
<link href="<?= base_url('asset/css/font-awesome.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I have applied css in a view file with head tag.
I am begginer in a codeigniter so,anyone have solutions for me.

Comment: try echo the path and check if file is there

Comment: I have tried echo but its not working.

Comment: @shraddha try this `<?php echo base_url();?>asset/css/font-awesome.css`

Comment: @shraddha it worked ??

Comment: No its not working.    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: In what folder is your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled `bae_url()` instead `base_url()`.
Change it to

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css');?>">
```

and in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/greenschool/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you forgot an s after asset since your other links use assets folder. Also in the screenshot you have typos in link for dataTables.bootstrap.css.